# ffmpeg stdout missing bytes

Tags: ffmpeg, stdout

Initial data:

- **ffmpeg version 2.7.2-static**

  built with gcc 4.9.3 (Debian 4.9.3-1)

  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-shared --disable-debug --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libwebp --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libfreetype --enable-fontconfig --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-gray --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libass --enable-gnutls --enable-libvidstab --enable-libsoxr --cc=gcc-4.9
- **video.mp4** the file is **31000079** bytes

The problem is:

- `cat video.mp4 | ffmpeg -i pipe: -v warning -vf scale=100:100 scaled_video.mp4` produces a file of **755052** bytes
- `cat video.mp4 | ffmpeg -i pipe: -v warning -vf scale=100:100 -f h264 - > scaled_video.mp4` produces a file of **252804** bytes

**ffprobe** shows that initial file video stream is **h264**

What can't i see ?:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why are you piping the input instead of `ffmpeg -i video.mp4`?

Anyway, it's not what can't you see but rather what can't you hear.

The first command scales the video and re-encodes the whole MP4 file, including all the audio tracks it might have, using the default ffmpeg parameters. It will compress your file.

The second command where you specify `-f h264` does the same but outputs just the **raw H.264** video stream and no audio. The resulting file is not a valid MP4, its extension should be `.h264`

`-f h264` is used for getting the raw H.264 stream. If you want to specify the codec then use `-c:v libx264` instead.